# How to get complete record element from PostgreSQL json_to_recordset() Function?

Tags: json, postgresql, json-extract

I want to extract the complete record elements from `json_to_recordset()`. How to get it.
Below is the description of my problem statement:

**Description**

I have one column with `JSON` Type and with the below value where each element of `JSON Array` are not necessarily has the same format. I want to convert this JSON Array into Table rows.

I have tried `json_to_recordset()` function available and I am also able to extract single elements from a row such as an `id` or `name` etc but not complete row.

```
[{"id":"1","type":"user","name":"AV","displayName":"Aviral","Company":"ABC","Age":34},
    {"id":"2","type":"user","name":"Ram","displayName":"Ram","City":"Jaipur"}]
```

My use case require to store the complete row as a single column how to get it in postgres.

Below logic, I have applied for a single field

```
SELECT json_to_recordset( data::json) as r(  id text, name text)
```

The **output** I am getting:

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `json_array_elements` to Expands a JSON array to a set of JSON values :

`->>` to get JSON object field as text

```
select row->>'id' as id, row->>'name' as name, row
FROM mytable, json_array_elements(myjson) row;
```

Result :

```
id  name    row
1   AV  {"id":"1","type":"user","name":"AV","displayName":"Aviral","Company":"ABC","Age":34}
2   Ram {"id":"2","type":"user","name":"Ram","displayName":"Ram","City":"Jaipur"}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ozmlmdQ7)